# Recoined is it a real word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology, inflectional-morphology

'coined' is past tense of 'coin' 
Is recoined a real word? It is not listed in Oxford dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for checking the dictionary before asking here! Even though your dictionary may not list it, "recoin" is in fact a word (and by extension, so is its past tense/past participle "recoined"). My favorite online resource for seeing if a word is listed in dictionaries is [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=recoin&ls=a). You can see that Collins, Merriam-Webster and Dictionary.com, among others, have entries for "recoin."

Comment: Could you please explain what “real word” means? Otherwise your question cannot be answered because it’s unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: Oddly, even though there is an entry for "recoin" in [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recoin), it doesn't show up as a OneLook search result. It's true that [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=recoin) doesn't have an entry for it–is that the dictionary you normally use?

Comment: Relevant: [Adding “re” prefix](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32294), [Is there any grammar rule for the usage of the re- prefix?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/271027)

Comment: Rule for 're' Use the hyphen with the prefix re only when re means again AND omitting the hyphen would cause confusion with another word.

Comment: So are we in agreement that the use of recoined is ok?

Comment: Check the Google Books search results that begin on [this page](https://www.google.com/#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22recoined%22). You'll find that a search for _recoined_ produces something in the vicinity of 170 unique matches in the published (and usually edited) texts included in the Google Books database.

Answer (score 1):

One test of whether something is a "real" word is whether people use it. If we consult the Ngram viewer, we find this example going back to 1805 from [*The Works, Political, Metaphysical, and Chronological, of the Late James Steuart*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jhtjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA421&dq=%22recoin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtk-DdoeXOAhXH5iYKHXBpDMUQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22recoin%22&f=false), Volume 2, Sir James Steuart, ed.

> But it may be found convenient, for removing the small fractions in
>   shillings and sixpences, to **recoin** such denominations all
>   together, and to put them to their integer numbers,....

English is fairly free in the use of prefixes (*re-*, *un-*, etc.) and suffixes (*-ness*, *-ly*, etc.), and dictionary makers don't have the space to include every combination of base word and affix.

In this instance, I think you're in good company with Sir James.