# Is "rescrew" a word or local dialect?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I heard people saying something like this:

> We have to "rescrew" [e.g.] a tissue box holster to the wall.

I'm not sure, is the syllable "re" common? It seems this is not too commonly used.

What are possible synonyms / more common terms?

Comment: If you can unscrew something you can rescrew it.

Comment: Mh okay. Seems plausible. Didn't find it in my dictionary... sorry. Should have paid more attention.

Comment: You generally won't find such terms in a dictionary, and the computer spell checkers will puke on them, but they are (for the most part) legit.  A purist might insist on a hyphen (re-screw), but that's distracting for such simple cases.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using the hyphen, but then would one use the hyphen also for unscrew? The latter word can be found in regular dictionaries without a hyphen.

Comment: *Unscrew* is found in dictionaries simply because it's more common.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. Then probably my question should be updated to: What are possible synonyms. :)

Comment: Related: [Adding “re” prefix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/adding-re-prefix). As mentioned there, hyphenation is rare, and usually only found to avoid confusion with another word, or to clarify that the "e" is not part of a vowel digraph like "ee". I don't think you are justified in calling this "not good language".

Comment: @HotLicks Enough if you can screw.

Comment: "To uncork corked bottles screw the corkscrew in the cork and screw. If you screw up unscrew the corkscrew and rescrew to unscrew what you have screwed up." (Carole Marsh, Arkansas "Crinkum-Crankum,"
p.57 ) https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=079334820X ‎Juvenile Nonfiction.

Comment: The other (probably more common) term is "screw back in" (or "screw back on", for a nut).

Comment: screw something ***in*** or rescrew or re-screw something ***in*** That gives you: rescrew the tissue box holder back ***into*** the wall. Online sites and comments often overlook crucial little details. You screw a person (in both senses) and you screw a thing into some other thing. There is no synonym for the verb screw when used to mean use a screw to attach something to something. My goodness....

Comment: @HotLicks I would definitely use the hyphen for "re-screw" for clarity's sake (when I first saw it I thought it was a mis-spelling of "rescue"). But I wouldn't bother with the hyphen for "unscrew", since there is no clarity issue at stake.

Comment: unscrew is useful for ELLing. To do, redo, undo; to screw, unscrew,re-screw; to write, rewrite, to stitch,restitch. Some "re's"are more common than others.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but I think this is substantially answered in *[Adding "re" prefix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/adding-re-prefix)*. Common affixes like *non-*, *un-*, *-ly*, *-ness*, *-y* are often employed to create nonce words whose meanings are readily understood, even if the resulting word is understood to be non-standard, much less appear in a dictionary.